# DB2 Case Statement - select lowest value if same maximum value

Tags: sql, db2, case

I am trying to write a sql in db2 with case statement for the following scenario. Based on a particular ID we have to find the maximum amount and flag the one with the maximum amount. But if there are two same maximum values, then we need to consider the lowest rank (in the order of 1,2,3,4,5 and then 0).

So in the below example, the max_amt_ind should be Y only for Rank 2 and N for rank 0 and 1.

```
ID      RANK    AMT     MAX_AMT_IND
13786   0       6.11    N
13786   1       2.9     N
13786   2       6.11    Y
```

The following query marks both Rank 0 and Rank 2 as ‘Y’. I also tried using nested case statement, but not able to find a solution. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
select a. id, a.rank,a. amt,b.max_amount,
case when a.amt=b.max_amount then 'Y'
            else 'N'
            end as max_amt_ind
from Table_1 a inner join 
( 
select id, max(amt) as max_amount from Table_1
where max_payer_ind is null and id=13786
group by id
) b on a. id=b. id
```

Thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `row_number()`:

```
select id, rank, amt,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by id
                                     order by amt desc,
                                              (case when rank = 0 then 1 else 0 end, rank desc)
                                    ) = 1
             then 'Y'
             else 'N'
        end) as MAX_AMT_IND
from . . .;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. But I cant use rank desc or rank asc since I have to consider Rank 0 at the end. So the order is Rank 1, Rank 2, Rank 3, Rank 4, Rank 5 and then Rank 0.

Comment: @Niki . . . I have no idea what your comment refers to.  The above query should return 'Y' for just the one row where you want it for the data in the OP.

Comment: Sorry if it was confusing. Let me put this way.                                         ID      RANK    AMT     MAX_AMT_IND
13786   0       6.11    N
13786   1       6.11    Y
13786   2       6.11    N    If the amount is same for all three records, the max_amt_ind should be 'Y' for rank 1 and 'N' for the other two records.

Answer (score 0):

I only noticed this topic per the recent activity, but because apparently not yet answered in a way considered acceptable, I thought I would offer a try, despite the advanced age of the OP.

Ignoring the possibility of what to do with a duplicate max(amt) value that lies outside of the rank-column values of 1 to 5, but is found with rank-column value of 0, the following seems possibly to be a valid solution for at least the two test-cases [one in the OP, the other in a comment in response to an answer]:

setup:

```
 create table table_1                     
 ( id        int                          
 , rank      dec(2)                       
 , amt       dec(5, 2)                    
 , max_payer_ind for mpi char default null
 )                                        
 ;
 insert into  table_1 values          
   ( 11786 , 0  ,    6.11  , default )
 , ( 11786 , 1  ,    6.11  , default )
 , ( 12786 , 0  ,    6.11  , default )
 , ( 12786 , 1  ,    6.11  , default )
 , ( 12786 , 2  ,    6.11  , default )
 , ( 13786 , 0  ,    6.11  , default )
 , ( 13786 , 1  ,    2.9   , default )
 , ( 13786 , 2  ,    6.11  , default )
 ;
```

The original query from the OP modified to use a scalar subselect in the CASE expression [not a CASE statement] to assign the desired value according to the column named RANK; using the original example with three rows of two distinct AMT values for id=13786, but adding a second example with two rows of equal AMT values for id=11786, and adding a third example [described in the comment @Niki Nov 7 '14 at 20:19] with three rows of identical AMT values for id=12786.

```
 select a.id, a.rank, a.amt, b.max_amount             
      , case a.rank when ( select min(nullif(rank, 0))
                           from table_1               
                           where id=a.id              
                             and amt=b.max_amount   ) 
                    then 'Y' else 'N'                 
        end as max_amt_ind                            
 from Table_1 a                                       
 inner join table                                     
      ( select id, max(amt) as max_amount             
        from Table_1                                  
        where max_payer_ind is null                   
          and id = a.id                               
        group by id                                   
      ) b                                             
   on a.id = b.id                                     
 -- report from above query follows:
       ID   RANK     AMT   MAX_AMOUNT  MAX_AMT_IND
   11,786     0     6.11       6.11         N     
   11,786     1     6.11       6.11         Y     
   13,786     0     6.11       6.11         N     
   13,786     1     2.90       6.11         N     
   13,786     2     6.11       6.11         Y     
   12,786     0     6.11       6.11         N     
   12,786     1     6.11       6.11         Y     
   12,786     2     6.11       6.11         N
```

Now in consideration of the duplicate max(amt) being in both the ranking=0 and a ranking>5, so as to make sense of assignment of the indicator, that "we need to consider the lowest rank (in the order of 1,2,3,4,5 and then 0)", I offer the following additional data for the test-case and the following revision to the query:

```
 insert into  table_1 values          
   ( 17786 , 0  ,    6.11  , default )
 , ( 17786 , 1  ,    1.11  , default )
 , ( 17786 , 2  ,    2.11  , default )
 , ( 17786 , 3  ,    3.11  , default )
 , ( 17786 , 4  ,    4.11  , default )
 , ( 17786 , 5  ,    5.11  , default )
 , ( 17786 , 6  ,    6.11  , default )
```

The query changes to enable a match to a.rank=0 [using IFNULL()] and elimination of consideration for assigning the indication to a ranking beyond 5 [by adding a predicate `rank<=5` for the scalar subselect]:

```
 select a.id, a.rank, a.amt, b.max_amount                  
      , case a.rank when ifnull(                           
                         ( select min(nullif(rank, 0))     
                           from table_1                    
                           where id=a.id                   
                             and rank<=5                   
                             and amt=b.max_amount   ) , 0 )
                    then 'Y' else 'N'                      
        end as max_amt_ind                                 
 from Table_1 a                          
 inner join table                        
      ( select id, max(amt) as max_amount
        from Table_1                     
        where max_payer_ind is null      
          and id = a.id                  
        group by id                      
      ) b        
   on a.id = b.id
 -- report from above query follows:
       ID   RANK     AMT   MAX_AMOUNT  MAX_AMT_IND
   11,786     0     6.11       6.11         N     
   11,786     1     6.11       6.11         Y     
   17,786     0     6.11       6.11         Y     
   17,786     1     1.11       6.11         N     
   17,786     2     2.11       6.11         N     
   17,786     3     3.11       6.11         N     
   17,786     4     4.11       6.11         N     
   17,786     5     5.11       6.11         N     
   17,786     6     6.11       6.11         N     
   13,786     0     6.11       6.11         N     
   13,786     1     2.90       6.11         N     
   13,786     2     6.11       6.11         Y     
   12,786     0     6.11       6.11         N     
   12,786     1     6.11       6.11         Y     
   12,786     2     6.11       6.11         N
```

So in the above results, we do not indicate the ranking=6 with the duplicate max(amt) value, but we finally have a case for which the rank=0 could actually qualify for the indication; i.e. without the duplicate max(amt) being outside the range of 1 to 5, there would never be an opportunity to indicate the rank=0 -- that is, if I understand the problem description.